# Server Header Checker

Tags: asp.net

how do i connect a web site and then how can i control its header/http status code in asp.net?

i tried HttpWebRequest/WebRequest/Stream class but i failed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the WebRequest class for this:

```
WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com");
wr.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Head;
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse())
{
    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
}
```

The line `wr.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Head;` makes the WebRequest object to retrieve the headers only (if this is the only thing you are interested in, there is no use downloading the full page). If you *want* the full page, use `wr.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;` instead.

Comment: thanks Fredrik, i am interested in only header... it is realy helpful :)